# Display image after the Category Image has

Tags: php, mysqli

right now and here I am in the process of preparing such that "gallery_kategori" should be an ID of the Gaul's category

Error appears and describes like this: Error 2: Commands out of sync; you can not run this command now

What I want out of:
- Would like it to go into the gallery and take a picture belonging than the category or area.
- It should not be together all the time and it should be only one image at a time for each image as that is.

```
function galleryKategori()
 {
     if ($st = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM gallery_kategori')) { 
         $st->execute();
         $st->bind_result($id, $title);
         while ($st->fetch()) {
         ?>
         <a href="/galleri-indhold/<?php echo $id;?>/">
             <div class="galleryKategori">
                 <h4><?php echo $title;?></h4>
                 <?php
                     if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT rank, img FROM gallery WHERE kategori = ?')) {
                         $stmt->bind_param('i', $kategori);
                         $kategori = $id;
                         $stmt->execute();
                         $stmt->bind_result($rank, $img);
                         while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                             if($rank == 2)
                             {

                             }
                         }
                         $stmt->close();
                     } else {
                         echo 'Error 2: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                     }
                 ?>
             </div>
         </a>
         <?php
         }
         $st->close();
     }
     else {
         echo 'Error 1: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
     }
 }
```

**EIDT VERSION**

```
function galleryKategori()
{
    $st->free_result();
    if ($st = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM gallery_kategori')) { 
        $st->execute();
        $st->bind_result($id, $title);
        while ($result->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <a href="/galleri-indhold/<?php echo $id;?>/">
            <div class="galleryKategori">
                <h4><?php echo $title;?></h4>
                <?php
                    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT rank, img FROM gallery WHERE kategori = ?')) {
                        $kategori = $id;
                        $stmt->bind_param('i', $kategori);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($rank, $img);
                        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                            if($rank == 2)
                            {
                                echo "Hey";
                            }
                        }
                        $stmt->close();
                    } else {
                        echo 'Error 2: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
        }
        $st->close();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error 1: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try declaring $kategori = $id; before you call $stmt->bind_param('i', $kategori);?

Comment: @Jason It may not work: (

Answer (score 0):

After some messing around with your code, it is because you haven't freed your first result with that connection.

You will need to use two MySQLi Objects or rewrite your code in a way where you are able to call `$st->free_result();` Before this line:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT rank, img FROM gallery WHERE kategori = ?')
```

That's all it took from me to have it working correctly.

**Edit 08/14/13:**

Since you asked, I would have removed the function (unless this is an object, which it doesn't look like it) and gone for a mix of inline and block php. I took some liberties with what you are going to do with your code, but here's a small example of something that might work. I store the result in an array, free the result, and reuse the same statement object.

```
<?php
    if( ( $st = $mysqli->prepare( 'SELECT id, title FROM gallery_kategori' ) ) !== FALSE ) {

        $st->execute();
        $st->bind_result( $id, $title );

        while( $st->fetch() ) {
            $categories[$id] = $title;
        }
        $st->free_result();
        unset( $id, $title );
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error 1: ' . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
<?php if( count( $categories ) > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $categories as $id => $title ): ?>
        <div class="galleryKategori">
            <h4>
                <a href="/galleri-indhold/<?php echo $id; ?>/">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
            <?php
                if( ( $st = $mysqli->prepare( 'SELECT rank, img FROM gallery WHERE kategori = ?' ) ) !== FALSE ) {

                    $st->bind_param( 'i', $id );
                    $st->execute();
                    $st->bind_result( $rank, $img );

                    while( $st->fetch() ) {
                        $gallery[$rank] = $img;
                    }
                    $st->free_result();
                    unset( $rank, $img );
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error 2: ' . $mysqli->error;
                }
            ?>
            <?php if( count( $gallery ) > 0 ): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach( $gallery as $rank => $img ): ?>
                        <li class="gallery rank-<?php echo $rank; ?>">
                            <a href="/galleri-indhold/<?php echo $id; ?>/">
                                <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="Image <?php echo $rank; ?>" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
                <ul>
                    <li>There are no images in this category.</li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Category Does Not Exist.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $mysqli->close(); ?>
```

**Notes**

- Restructure your html elements, an inline element (anchor) should not contain a block element (div). I updated the code above to show it appropriately.

Comment: Added my code to my answer, we volunteers at SE work for tips in the form of rep ;). Don't forget to select your answer if it solves your problem best.